# How to access the objects property using generic

Tags: java, arrays, generics, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement Data into my ArrayBST class using generic and it looks like this:

```
    public class ArrayBST<Data extends Comparable<? super Data>>{
    private Data[] data;
    private String[] array;
    //constructors
    public ArrayBST() {
    }

    public ArrayBST(int initialCapacity) {
    array= new String[initialCapacity];
    }

    }
```

And in the ArrayBST class there will be methods such as finding the height and size of this array_based search tree. I have to test it by scanning the words in a file and returning the word as a string and its frequency as an integer. Therefore, I have created another class called Text which looks like this:

```
    public class Text implements Comparable<Text> {

    public String word;
    public int frequency;

    // constructor
    public Text(String word, int frequency){
    this.word=word;
    this.frequency=frequency;

    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Text arg0) {
    String otherWord = arg0.word;
    int compare=word.compareTo(otherWord);

    return compare;
    }
    }
```

And in my main method, I will create a the BST_array using the Text class like this:

```
    ArrayBST<Text> bst_array = new ArrayBST<Text>(100);
```

However, I don't know how to access to the properties of the Text (i.e. String word and int frequency) in my BSTArray class using Data. Can I do a private constructor for Data instead? If not, how can I do it. I need to use the properties of my Text Object in some methods. Now I am stuccoed and don't know how to continue... Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Comment: Your "Data" is a generic type, and is erased at run-time (compile time type checking only). Your bst_array has elements of type `Text`.

Comment: You need to decide: if your ArrayBST needs to be implemented using methods in Text, it can only contain Text, so there's no point in making it generic.  If you want it to be generic, you have to find a way to implement it without tying it to Text, perhaps using Visitor pattern.

Comment: (It's a good idea to avoid arrays of reference types. They play badly with everything else.)

Comment: I agree with @antlersoft. You are looking for specific-ability BST or Generic one because they contradict each other.